# How to add sliding animation MUI using CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am facing an issue of adding the slide animation on the question and answer. I want on click of the radio button the slide effect comes and next question comes with Slideup animation.

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={8}>
  
    <Slide direction="up"  
    in={checked} 
    appear={true} 
    mountOnEnter 
             unmountOnExit
    timeout={{ enter: 1000 , exit: checked ? 1 : 900}}
>   
        <Card variant="outlined" sx={{ bgcolor: "#bea"}} elevation={0}>
            <CardContent>

            <form onSubmit= {handleSubmit}>
                    <CardActions>
                  <Button type="submit" color="warning" variant="outlined" disabled={currentQuestion===0} className={classes.button} onClick={previousQuestion}>
                      Previous</Button>
                  </CardActions>              
                  <FormControl component='fieldset' className={classes.formControl}
    data-hidden={questions[currentQuestion].number !==
      currentQuestion[questions[currentQuestion] .number]} >
    <FormLabel component='legend'>
      {questions[currentQuestion].question}
    </FormLabel>
    <FormLabel component='legend'>
      {questions[currentQuestion].description}
    </FormLabel>
    <RadioGroup
      aria-label='quiz'
      name='quiz'
      value={questions[currentQuestion].value}
      checked={checked}
      onChange={(e)=> handleRadioChange(questions[currentQuestion].number, e)}
      sx={{
        color: pink[800],
        '&.Mui-checked': {
          color: blue[600],
        },
      }}>
      {options.map((option) => (
        <FormControlLabel
          key={option.score}
          value={option.score}
          control={<Radio  sx={{
            color: pink[800],
            '&.Mui-checked': {
              color: blue[600],
            },
          }}/>}
          label={option.label}
         
        />
      ))}
    </RadioGroup>
  </FormControl>
                    <CardActions>
                    <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} disabled={currentQuestion != 5} onClick={handleSubmit}>
                    Submit
                </Button>
              </CardActions>
                </form>
                </CardContent>
                </Card>
                </Slide>
```

This is not working smoothly. So please help. The problem is on click of previous button the value disappeared. The slide effect is not flawless.

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing the problem.

Comment: it is bit difficult for me to post the code in sandbox. can you provide the solution @Ryan Cogswell

Comment: I'm not going to try to provide a solution without having a sandbox in which to see the current behavior and in which to verify potential solutions.

Comment: Oh then please wait I am making a codesandbox link, it will take another 10 mins

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-nova-1vd86t?file=/src/Quiz.js  hey please check @Ryan Cogswell

Comment: Make sure you have saved the latest version. Right now it just displays an error.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-nova-1vd86t?file=/src/Quiz.js
hi Sorry for the long delay, have kept the latest version @Ray Cogswell : please check

Comment: Still displays an error. Open the link in an incognito browser window to verify the sandbox link. When you are working in a sandbox, it will show changes that you make even if you haven’t saved the changes, but if you don’t save, others will not be able to see those unsaved changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244888/discussion-between-tanya-maheshwari-and-ryan-cogswell).